# Display '&apos;' in IE

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer

I want to display `&apos;` on a web page but it displays the apostrophe character instead of `&apos;`

Is it possible to display `&apos;` on a webpage?

Comment: Didn't you just do it?

Comment: @Will I laughed, but StackOverflow is escaping the `&amp;` for him. Imagine how frustrating this question would have been to ask if it didn't!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to say "Display an & character" instead of "Start a character reference", then you need to use a character reference to represent it: `&amp;` (so `&amp;apos;`).

Comment: specifically, it would be something like `&amp;apos;`

Comment: I am doing the same but still i have issue. I am keeping my xml code here
nameStrID=\"E000000B7E\"/>\r\n\t\t<param value=\"Engine RH -Additional OEM/Vehicle Diagnostic Codes have been logged. Check other ECM&amp;apos;s for DTC&amp;apos;s. - CFC Code: 211\"

Comment: What are you *doing* with the XML? You tagged this question with `html`, so presumably you aren't just opening it by typing the URL to the XML file in the address bar.

Comment: @Sijith You should probably edit your question if you have something like this to post. It is difficult to read in a comment. If the apostrophe thing is displaying now, you should mark this answer as correct, not just get poor Quentin to debug all of your code.

Comment: I am sending the data using my C++ program and later it get displayed on Webpage as Quentin suggested i kept &amp;apos; and it worked great for IE but in mozilla &amp is displatying :(

Comment: You should really consider feeding you output into the w3 validator

Answer (score 0):

you should use `&amp;apos;` .